# ¿Cómo poner los ultimos div en la primera posición?

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando la forma de 'girar' los `div` y dejarlos en el orden correcto, `1,2,3...`. De igual manera, que la posición sea la que se obtiene con JavaScript, ya que por ejemplo, el 10 sería el objeto `[0]`, entonces, al girar, el `div` 1 quede con la posición `[0]`.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

```html
<div class="list-div">
  <div>10</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta el código que tienes para realizar lo que quieres de resultado; y que indiques que obtienes para que así, llegue la lluvia de ideas que puedes aplicar.

Answer (score 1):

Exactamente no sé cómo estás usando tu lista con JavaScript, pero si solamente se trata de girar la lista, sería muy fácil con **CSS**:

```
.list-div {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende muy bien. Pero la necesidad al parecer está clara, si necesitas invertir en este caso un arreglo **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, n...]** puedes usar el método ***reverse()***.

[Aquí te dejo información al respecto.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 0):

Usando Flexbox puede hacer eso...

```
.list-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items:center
}
```

Comment: La propiedad flex-direction con un valor de row no parece ser necesaria, si la quitas igual debe funcionar

Comment: Por defecto display:flex tiene como eje principal el eje X, si necesitas usar el Y necesitas colocar 'row'

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Precisamente, lo menciono por que en el código que expones esa propiedad que digo esta de mas, por que los vas a distribuir sobre x, de hecho si quieres a los elementos pero sobre el eje y lo que se usa es column, te invito a que leas el enlace que me compartes

Answer (score 0):

> En esta publicación se explica cómo cambiar el orden de los elementos utilizando JavaScript y luego CSS.

### Cambiar el orden de los elementos

Si busca cambiar el orden de los elementos contenidos en `.list-div` con JavaScript puede hacer lo siguiente:

Obtenemos su contenedor (`.list-div`):

```js
const listDiv = document.querySelector(".list-div");
```

Almacenamos en un *array* los elementos hijos de `listDiv` y llamamos al método `reverse()` para invertir su orden antes de enviarlos al *array* `elementos`:

```js
const elementos = [...listDiv.childNodes].reverse();
```

> Note que utilizamos el operador de propagación (...) para copiar la lista de nodos en elementos individuales. La idea es tener `[object Array]` en lugar de `[object NodeList]` para poder utilizar el método `reverse()`.

Borramos los elementos del contenedor `listDiv`:

```js
listDiv.textContent = "";
```

Y finalmente, utilizamos nuestro bucle para incorporar los elementos a su contenedor en orden inverso:

```js
for ( let elemento of elementos ) {
    listDiv.appendChild( elemento );
}
```

### Ejecutar ejemplo

Como ya se tiene claro lo anteriormente expuesto podemos integrar en la siguiente *demo* el código completo:

```js
const listDiv = document.querySelector(".list-div");
const elementos = [...listDiv.childNodes].reverse();

listDiv.textContent = "";
for ( let elemento of elementos ) {
    listDiv.appendChild( elemento );
}
```

```html
<div class="list-div">
  <div>10</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es con CSS, por ejemplo:

```css
.list-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-div">
  <div>10</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

> En ambos casos, el resultado visual es el mismo, pero es diferente semánticamente.

Tome en cuenta que para utilizar la propiedad `flex-direction` debe estar la propiedad `display` con el valor `flex` o `inline-flex`.